# Handling large amount of data

Tags: .net, wcf, architecture, salesforce

We are looking at integrating our platform with Salesforce via Salesforce Outbound Messaging (SOM). Every time client updates an object(s) in Salesforce, SOM will call our Webservice endpoint with the updated object(s) (up to 100 objects in a single call). Our Webservice needs to update corresponding records in our database.

SOM works quite well for our purposes except for 1 issue.

Some clients do mass nightly updates. It is not unusual for 200,000-500,000 objects to be updated. This means we will get 2,000-5,000 calls with 100 objects in very short time period. Our Webservice will be overwhelmed with so much data specially if multiple clients do mass updates close to each other.

To deal with this large volume/spike Webserver will create message on Application server for each object in the SOM call. Another process will take messages from Message Queue and update the database.

[MSMQ is only limited by hardware](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/02/29/what-are-msmq-s-limits-if-i-had-a-farthing-for-every-time.aspx) so should be able handle millions of messages whilst we clear backlog.

The main question is this good design for dealing large amount of data/webservice calls? Is there better method?

Comment: 5000 calls is way less than 400,000 message limit that you're worried about, what's the problem?

Comment: I have reworded my question so hopefully the question is more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're concerned about your system's ability to handle a large volume from salesforce in a short period of time, perhaps you should look at the [replication api](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_guidelines_datareplication.htm). It's more of a pull model. You call salesforce when you're ready to consume more data.

Editing to add that if storing a message in a queue is significantly cheaper than doing the ultimate processing of the message (which seems to be the case here), using a message queue seems like a good plan. I'm only nominally familiar with MSMQ. But assuming it's remotely as enterprise grade as many of the free JMS queues, it should be up to the task.

Comment: We have considered Replication API (pull model). Push model is more suitable for our system as clients data is more likely to be in sync with Salesforce data.

Comment: What does salesforce guarantee for time to attempt delivery for OBM? Consider the answer to this versus the fact that you can call getUpdated() whenever you want. Not saying one is better, just something to think about.

Comment: Good point. I haven't found any guarantees for time to attempt delivery.

Comment: Looks like we are leaning towards using Replication API (pull model). We have more control as it is flexible. Also, Outbound Messages are not triggered upon object deletes.

Answer (score 1):

Are you just looking for a simple queue that basically stores the web service requests for asynchronous ordered processing at leisure, rather than synchronously? If so, fully-fledged MQ services are WAY overkill. It's a fairly trivial (minus obvious multithreading gotchas) to produce an in-memory queue that is capable of storing 100's of k's of work requests, and that can flush its state to disk or be DB-backed. Even from scratch, although there are plenty of lightweight libraries for Java and .NET that would help with this.

NoSQL solutions like Redis would be viable options too (Redis probably superior compared to other NoSQL options because of native support for lists and hashes, plus easy disk flushing). Amazon SQS would give you insanely cheap+scalable message storage in the cloud which would be a plus if you are looking for resilience - you could freely take down your processing endpoint for hours at a time with no apparent visibility to the end client, and all the cool toys you get "out of the box" with AWS.

Answer (score 1):

I would not store one object per message, but one set of objects (one SOM message) per your local message queue. Remember that once you've replied with an Ack to salesforce, you need to take ownership of the message persistence/recovery etc, I'd think MSMQ is a fine fit.

One alternative is to just let them queue up at Salesforce, if your listener is overworked it can Nack the request from Salesforce, and Salesforce will requeue the message and try it again later (and so on, for upto 24 hours), if burst capacity is your only concern, this would help with that. (this assumes you don't have timeliness requirements, as you'd be out of control of when those retries happen)

Comment: We intend to respond with Ack immediately and then create message(s) on a remote MSMQ. At the moment considering creating 1 message per 1 object because of 4MB size limit of MSMQ message. The aim is to have data synced as much as possible so Nack response is not a viable solution (although we have considered it).